# How canI check null of a new contract

Tags: solidity

I get `Test1` from `Test2.map`, before I use `Test1` function, how can I check null of Test1?

Code:

```
contract Test1 {
    function someFunc() public {}
}

contract Test2 {
    mapping(uint => Test1) map;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Im Solidity, the values of mappings are 0 at default. So, of you want to find out whether an entry hasn't been set yet, try this:

```
if(map[key]!=address(0)){
    map[key].someFunc()
} else {
    // it's not set! 
}
```

Comment: btw, the " ! " after " if( " is a mistake?

Comment: Correct, i'll change that :)